# Using PowerShell, how do I extract just the file path and name from a line of text?

Tags: regex, powershell, split, substring

If I am iterating through a text document with each line has an output something like this:

```
        Newer             432416 2020/04/04 01:50:14    S:\Steam\SteamLibrary\steam.dll
```

I just want to extract the filename and path: `S:\Steam\SteamLibrary\steam.dll`

I know if I store that line in a variable `$textline = "        Newer             432416 2020/04/04 01:50:14    S:\Steam\SteamLibrary\steam.dll"`

I can simply use `$textline.split (":")[-1]` which results in:

```
\Steam\SteamLibrary\steam.dll
```

But how do I get it to include the drive letter `S:` ? Is there a way to tell it to grab one character before as well as include the delimiter?

Thank you.

Comment: What about `[regex]::split($textline, "\s{2}")[-1]`?

Comment: You might want to look at the bigger picture (are there headers in the **text document**? could there be spaces in the filename/path "property"?).  Anyways try this [ConvertFrom-SourceTable](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable); if there are no headers: `$textline | ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Header Newer,Size,Date,Time,Filepath`. If there are headers in your **text document**, just: `$textdocument | ConvertFrom-SourceTable | Foreach { $_.<filepath header> }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below regex match to search for the file path in each line

```
([A-Z]:\\(?:[^\\]+\\)*[^\\]+)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`[A-Z]:`** - Matches the drive name followed by literal `:`. In the script I used `?i` for case-insensitive match.
- **`\\(?:[^\\]+\\)*`** - `\`(since it's a special character so it needs to be escaped) followed by a non-capturing group which matches atleast one character except(`\`). The non-capturing group can exist 0 or more time since there can be nested paths. Here, you can also include newline negation list. See *[here](https://regex101.com/r/XDuvVf/1)*. I have not done this since we are iterating over a line so it is not required.
- **`[^\\]+`** - Finally, this part matches any character that is not a backslash basically matching the filename of the path.
- **`$`** - Represents end of line.

```bash
$text_file = "path_to_your_file.ext"
$lines = Get-Content $text_file
$pattern = "(?i)([A-Z]:\\(?:[^\\]+\\)*[^\\]+)$"

foreach ($textline in $lines) {
    $match = [regex]::Match($textline, $pattern)

    if ($match.Success) {
        $file_path = $match.Groups[1].Value
        Write-Host $file_path
    }
}
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/W8jmz5/1)**

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will give this a try! I'm not too familiar with regex I guess I'll have to read up on it some more. I was also thinking that if it's a UNC path starting with double slash `\\`. Using the demo site you provided I managed to get UNC path worked, but not sure if it's optimal or even correct: https://regex101.com/r/4Yyl1G/1

Comment: @HTWingNut I'll help you with that. So you're saying what if the path starts with double slash and no drive path ryt?

Comment: Yes! Well it could be drive letter with colon or double slash to start.

Comment: @HTWingNut, ok then you can just use an alternation. Something like https://regex101.com/r/uXkZzc/1

Comment: This looks like it may work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

mandy8055's answer carefully checks whether the path is valid, but if you know that the file path is always at the end of the `$textLine`, and that the "columns" in the `$textLine` is separated with 4 spaces (or more), this regex is much faster:

```
^(?>.*\s{4})(.*)$
```

The logic with this regex is to simply find all the characters after the "last 4 whitespaces", there is no checking to see if it is a path.

Usage Example:

```
if($textLine -match "^(?>.*\s{4})(.*)$"){
    $path = $matches[1]
    # process the path etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on whitespace and take the last thing.

```
(-split '        Newer             432416 2020/04/04 01:50:14    S:\Steam\SteamLibrary\steam.dll')[-1]

S:\Steam\SteamLibrary\steam.dll
```